# applying onehotencoder on numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am applying OneHotEncoder on numpy array.

Here's the code

```
print X.shape, test_data.shape #gives 4100, 15) (410, 15)
onehotencoder_1 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12])
X = onehotencoder_1.fit_transform(X).toarray()
onehotencoder_2 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12])
test_data = onehotencoder_2.fit_transform(test_data).toarray()

print X.shape, test_data.shape #gives (4100, 46) (410, 43)
```

where both `X` and `test_data` are `<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`

`X` is my train set while `test_data` my test set.

How come the no. of columns different for `X` & `test_data`. they should be **46** or either **43** for both after applying onehotencoder.

I am applying OnehotEncoder on specific attributes as they are categorical in nature in both `X` and `test_data`

Can someone point out what is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a new OneHotEncoder on `test_data`, use the first one, and only use `transform()` on it. Do this:

```
test_data = onehotencoder_1.transform(test_data).toarray()
```

Never use `fit()` (or `fit_transform()`) on testing data.

The different number of columns are entirely possible because it may happen that test data dont contain some categories which are present in train data. So when you use a new OneHotEncoder and call `fit()` (or `fit_transform()`) on it, it will only learn about categories present in `test_data`. So there will be difference between the columns.

Comment: I think you mean to say Do this `test_data = onehotencoder_1.transform(test_data).toarray()`.....right ? while you accidentally wrote this `test_data = onehotencoder_1.fit_transform(test_data).toarray()` ?

Comment: @Guru Yes. Sorry, that was a copy paste typo. Corrected now.

Comment: Thanks @Vivek. Can you also throw light on how to get rid of dummy variable trap in using OnehotEncoder. I have read about it at many places, and people suggests to drop on column.
How do i drop column here and which column to drop ?

Comment: @Guru That is not that simple to do in OneHotEncoder. You have to write a custom class for that. For each category defined in `categorical_features`, there will be a column to remove. You can use `pandas.get_dummies()` but that wont work well with train and test split.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. As mentioned by you `For each category defined in categorical_features, there will be a column to remove` which column ? How to decide that ?
I can write a custom class. Any resource explaining same would be really helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Guru Most libraries remove the first column (level) in the transformed data. You can check the source code of [OneHotEncoder on the github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L1840) for starting